Trying to understand why the Sieve of Eratosthenes works
I am trying to understand how the Sieve of Eratosthenes works. I understand the algorithm of course, but I do not understand why it works. I know it is based on the fact that every composite integer k, greater than 1, has a prime factor which is not bigger than the square root of k. However, I do not understand how the two are linked. Specifically, if we have to find the primes between 2 and 100, why do we only have to eliminate the multiples of the (positive) primes not bigger than 10, i.e. 2,3,5,7?

Note that the next prime is 11, and 11 times 11 is 121 (bigger than 100).

What about 11*2 = 22?

$22$ is a multiple of $2$, so has been crossed out already.

You deleted your question before I could post the closure comment explanation so I added it to your question.

In general suppose you want to find out if $n$ is a prime. If it is not prime, then the smallest prime factor is $\leq \sqrt n$. To see this let $ab=n$, and let $a$ be the smallest prime factor. If $a>\sqrt n$ then we have $$ab<(\sqrt n)^2=n$$ which is impossible.
Another way to think about it: 
Let the area of the rectangle be $n$. Then you want to find $a,b$ such that $ab=n$. You start dividing $n$ by $1, 2, \ldots$. The worst case is when $a^2=n$, because then you'll have to check the numbers $1,2\ldots, \lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$, so you don't have to check if $n$ is divisible by a larger number.
For the primes less than 100, the smallest prime factor of any composite number must be less than $10=\sqrt{100}$. If a number is composite and has a smallest factor $\geq 10$ then that number is atleast $100$, so the remaining numbers which is not divisible by $2,3,5,7$ must be prime.

It should be $>$ instead of $<$.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

Let $p$ and $q$ be positive integers (they don’t even have to be primes) with both $p^2$ and $q^2$ greater than some integer  $n$.
Then there clearly exist positive integers $a$ and $b$ with $p^2 = n + a$ and $q^2 = n +b$.
This means that
$$(pq)^2 = p^2 q^2 = n^2 +(a+b)n + ab > n^2.$$
And since $x^2$ is increasing on ${\textbf R}^2$, this means $pq > n$.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

Mea culpa, @BillDubuque. Mea maxima culpa.
